# How to customize a character instead of $ or # in the xml file?

Tags: mybatis

My project code is scanned by fortify, it report that the character of $ has the risk about sql injection. But the code is generated by mybatis-gererator automatically, the $ is just table's column variate. There is not risk actually but reported. How can i do? The result of report cannot ignore.

Comment: `${}` is completely safe if you use it properly and you cannot always replace `${}` with `#{}` because they serve different purposes. I assume there is a way to disable this particular check in Fortify. If not, you should report it to Fortify's developer. Reporting every `${}` as a vulnerability is plain wrong anyway.

Comment: Got it, thx for your answer.